# In magento the save credit card feature needs to function similar to Amazon

Tags: payment-methods

In magento the save credit card feature needs to function similar to Amazon. They allow you to save you credit card on file so you don't have to enter it every time you come back and place an order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to see how your payment gateway handles card tokenisation and then implement this within the Magento extension for your gateway.  It's not something Magento can do natively.